# How to connect from docker container to a spring boot ap on localhost windows

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-network

I have two application, one Spring Boot which run on my windows localhost machine at port:8080, and one Spring Boot docker container, which run at localhost:9000 - yes, i can access it in postam at that port, both of them.
Thing is, i have in spring boot docker container a call to Spring Boot service located on windows machine, and when i call that endpoint, i got this error:

```
failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8080] with root cause
java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
```

My questions are, how can i change in my spring boot docker container app.yaml to be able to call that endpoint located on windows machine?

I'm running docker desktop on windows 10, i used --net=host but not working, and i don't know if i use host.docker.internal/8080 is going to be a success..

Answer (score -1):

The reason why Postman works is simple: When you run a docker container, port forwarding is done to the port on localhost of the application inside the container.

The reason for the problem is that the Docker container itself has a separate environment and its own OS. If you make a request to localhost:9000 from an application in a Docker container, it will not send a request to localhost:9000 on Windows, but instead it will send a request to localhost of the Linux running in the container. And it cannot find the required running application from linux, because the required application is running on localhost of Windows.

Localhost in a docker container is Linux localhost and not Windows. You should not write localhost:9000 in this case, for example 192.168.1.100:9000, everything will work if there are no problems with firewall and network.

Note 192.168.1.100:9000 may be different on your computer. In Windows, you can find out your IP address by typing `ipconfig` in cmd. You can find the IP here:

[image: IPv4 field in the output of ipconfig]